# Cannot accept invitation from devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am using [devise invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) in my app and for some reason I cannot accept the invitation.  When inspecting the logs I keep seeing the message:

```
Filter chain halted as :resource_from_invitation_token rendered or redirected
```

When inspecting the Devise code, I see the function is:

```
  def resource_from_invitation_token
    unless params[:invitation_token] && self.resource = resource_class.find_by_invitation_token(params[:invitation_token], true)
      set_flash_message(:alert, :invitation_token_invalid) if is_flashing_format?
      redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    end
  end
```

The part causing the issue is the `resource_class.find_by_invitation_token(params[:invitation_token], true)` becuase when I attempt to run `User.find_by_invitation_token(TOKEN, true)`, it comes up as `nil` in my console.

When I pull up the user in question and check it's `:invitation_token` it is **not** equal to the value being checked when attempting to accept the invitation

```
# User that is attempting to accept the invitation
> #<User id: 20786, email: "email_goes_here", created_at: "2018-11-06 19:39:29", updated_at: "2018-11-06 19:39:29", admin: false, employee: false, is_client: true, user_type: 5.0, location_id: 1, auth_token: nil, unlock: nil, deleted_at: nil, user_types_id: nil>

# Token from activation email
2.3.4 :003 > token = "GajU3sLy3r5exmzfqWKw" 
 => "GajU3sLy3r5exmzfqWKw"

# Should return the user, but instead returns nil
2.3.4 :004 > User.find_by_invitation_token(token, true)
  User Load (4.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["invitation_token", "b821be248a157559b10b7e5b908effd9fa13ec158cfb26b8d908cbad7f57f59e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil

# Should return value being used in find_by_invitation_token "b821be248a1..." but returns something else
2.3.4 :006 > User.last.invitation_token
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "fc56c527eba7fcf0b821a1289bf9083563527cd41612057521e173f26930f7f4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone runs into this question in the future, this is my understanding of Devise Invitable:

On the initial INVITE of a user it creates a raw token value (temporary accessor value of `raw_invitation_token` on the invitable object and then hashes that into the `invitation_token` field on the model.

So, the value in the url is the 'raw' token and then Devise Invitable does a one way hash lookup, for security purposes, to see if `raw_invitation_token` -> one way hash algorithm -> model's `invitation_token` value in database returns anything.

If it does NOT find any values based on that lookup, it silently fails.